# Qt, reading data from the Tableview model

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code. In the first method I create a table within the tableview. In the second method I try to get a value of a single cell from the tableview model (table). My try just doesn't work. Could you help me, please?

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int nrows = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();
    int ncols = nrows;

    ncols++;

    if (ui->radioButton_2->isChecked() == 1)
    {
        ncols*=2;
    }

    QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel( nrows, ncols, this );

    if ((ui->radioButton_2)->isChecked()==1)
    {
        for (int r=0; r<ncols-2; r++)
        {
            if(r%2==0)
            {
                model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( r, new QStandardItem( QString("x%0.a" ).arg(r/2+1)) );
            }
            else
            {
                model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( r, new QStandardItem( QString("x%0.b" ).arg(r/2+1)) );
            }
        }
        model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( ncols-2, new QStandardItem( QString("RHS.a" )) );
        model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( ncols-1, new QStandardItem( QString("RHS.b" )) );
    }
    else
    {
        for (int r=0; r<ncols-1; r++)
        {
            model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( r, new QStandardItem( QString("x%0" ).arg(r+1)) );
        }
        model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( ncols-1, new QStandardItem( QString("RHS" ) ));
    }

    for( int r=0; r<nrows; r++ )
    {
        for( int c=0; c<ncols; c++)
        {
            QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString(""));
            model->setItem(r, c, item);
        }
    }

    // Set model.
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QString text = ui->tableView->model()->item(0,0)->accessibleText();
    ui->label_2->setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(ui->tableView->model());
QString text = model->item(0,0)->text();
```

`accessibleText()` is for text set with `setAccessibleText()`

Comment: error: 'class QAbstractItemModel' has no member named 'item'
     QString text = ui->tableView->model()->item(0,0)->text();
                                            ^